# Get the start and end timestamp of the given timestamp in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I had a timestamp in Unix with milliseconds, now I need the start of the day and end of the day with milliseconds for the same given timestamp.

```
Eg:  1637293359000 - Given timestamp
Start of the day to be 1637280000000
End of the day to be 1637323199000
```

Comment: In what timezone?  The "start of the day" is different depending on what timezone you're in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this using DateTime

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

long timestamp = 1629454215381L;
DateTime dateTime=new DateTime(timestamp ); 

long StartOfDayMillis = dateTime.withMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()).withTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis();
long EndOfDayMillis = dateTime.withMillis(StartOfDayMillis).plusDays(1).minusSeconds(1).getMillis();
```

Comment: The [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance-mode. Its creator Stephen Colebourne went on to lead JSR 310 defining the *java.time* classes now built into Java. While Joda-Time continues to be updated, no more feature work will be done. The project advises migration to *java.time*.

Answer (score 1):

In System default timezone you could try like this

```
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    long timestamp = 1637293359000L;
    LocalDate date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(zoneId).toLocalDate();
    LocalDateTime startDay = date.atStartOfDay();
    LocalDateTime endDay = date.atTime(LocalTime.MAX);
    System.out.println(startDay);
    System.out.println(endDay);
    long startDayLongValue = startDay.atZone(zoneId).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    long endDayLongValue = endDay.atZone(zoneId).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(startDayLongValue);
    System.out.println(endDayLongValue);
```

Comment: This might be a little simpler noticing that the end of the day is the start of the next day.  I might also recommend just having a variable for the timezone, instead of passing in `systemDefault` everywhere.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to use here.

Comment: Days do not always start at 00:00. Nor does a day necessarily end at `23:59:59.999999999`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Here is the complete code to a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) representing the day of a specified moment as seen in a particular time zone. A static factory method contains our logic.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.Objects;

public record DayInMillis( long start , long end )
{
    public static DayInMillis from ( final long countOfMillisSinceEpoch , final ZoneId zoneId )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( zoneId );

        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( countOfMillisSinceEpoch );
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
        LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
        ZonedDateTime start = ld.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
        ZonedDateTime end = ld.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( zoneId );
        Instant startInstant = start.toInstant();
        Instant endInstant = end.toInstant();
        long startMilli = startInstant.toEpochMilli();
        long endMilli = endInstant.toEpochMilli();

        System.out.println( "instant = " + instant );
        System.out.println( "zdt = " + zdt );
        System.out.println( "start/end = " + start + "/" + end );
        System.out.println( "startInstant/endInstant = " + startInstant + "/" + endInstant );
        System.out.println( "startMilli/endMilli = " + startMilli + "/" + endMilli );
        System.out.println( "Duration (not necessarily 24 hours): " + Duration.between( startInstant , endInstant ) );

        return new DayInMillis( startMilli , endMilli );
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```java
DayInMillis.from( 1_637_293_359_000L , ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )
```

When run.

```
instant = 2021-11-19T03:42:39Z
zdt = 2021-11-19T12:42:39+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
start/end = 2021-11-19T00:00+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]/2021-11-20T00:00+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
startInstant/endInstant = 2021-11-18T15:00:00Z/2021-11-19T15:00:00Z
startMilli/endMilli = 1637247600000/1637334000000
Duration (not necessarily 24 hours): PT24H
dayInMillis = DayInMillis[start=1637247600000, end=1637334000000]
```

## Parse count of seconds

Parse your input count of milliseconds since epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC as a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_637_293_359_000L ) ;
```

## Adjust into time zone

Specify the time zone by which you want to perceive dates.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
```

Adjust from UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) to that time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

## Get the date

Extract the date-only portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

## Start of day

Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day. Never assume the day starts at 00:00. Some dates in some zones may start at another time such as 01:00.

```
ZonedDateTime start = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## Half-Open

The last moment of the day is infinitely divisible. For this and other reasons, spans of time are usually best defined using Half-Open approach. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This means the span of a day starts at the first moment of the day and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the *following* day.

```
ZonedDateTime end = ld.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Now we have the span covered by a pair of `ZonedDateTime` objects. But you want to get a count of milliseconds since epoch for both of those.

## Tracking count-from-epoch is awkward

Let me say, I do not recommend using a count-since-epoch for time-keeping. The values are inherently ambiguous as to both epoch and granularity. Furthermore, using such counts makes debugging difficult and errors hard to spot, as such values are meaningless to human readers.

### ISO 8601

Instead, I suggest communicating such values textually in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
String outputStart = start.toInstant().toString();
String outputEnd = end.toInstant().toString();
```

## Milliseconds since epoch

But if you insist on the count of milliseconds, first extract `Instant` objects from our `ZonedDateTime` objects, effectively adjusting to UTC (offset of zero).

```
Instant startInstant = start.toInstant() ;
Instant endInstant = end.toInstant() ;
```

Interrogate for a count of milliseconds since epoch.

```
long startMilli = startInstant.toEpochMilli() ;
long endMilli = endInstant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

## Avoid `LocalDateTime` for this problem

Notice that at no point did we use the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class. That class purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline. That makes `LocalDateTime` irrelevant to the problem at hand.

## Tip: *ThreeTen-Extra* library

If you routinely work with pairs of moments, considering adding the [`ThreeTen-Extra`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This provides the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class for representing a pair of `Instant` objects. The class carries several handy comparison methods such as `abuts`, `overlaps`, `contains`, and so on.